# Ionic "Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'"

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I made some minor changes to one of my views in my application, and am now getting a fatal error as seen below:

```
Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'
```

I have checked for cyclical references, and issues in the app.module but have been able to see anything that would be causing the issue.  Below are the functions of the classes that changed since the crash

Below is my medHist:

```
populatePage(id){
        console.log("single-test populate page testID");
        console.log(id);
        this.restService.getMedHist(id)
        .then(data => {
            console.log("patient data");
            console.log(data);
            this.medicalHistory = data;
            this.obField = this.medicalHistory.ob;
            this.gynField = this.medicalHistory.gyn;
            this.pmhField = this.medicalHistory.pmh;
            this.pshField = this.medicalHistory.psh;
            this.medsField = this.medicalHistory.meds;
            this.allField = this.medicalHistory.allVal;
            this.shField = this.medicalHistory.sh;
            console.log("data assigned");
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        }); 
    }
```

Rest-services:

```
getMedHistory(id) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('/getMedHist/' + id)
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log("rest-services.ts medHistory");
            this.medHistData = data;
            console.log(this.medHistData);
            resolve(this.medHistData);
        });
    });
}
```

below is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { MedHist } from '../pages/medHist/medHist';
import { AuthService } from '../providers/auth/auth';
import { RestService } from '../providers/rest-service/rest-service';
import { ShareServiceProvider } from '../providers/share-service/share-service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AllPatientsPage,
    MedHist
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AllPatientsPage,
    MedHist
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    ShareServiceProvider,
    RestService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Are you sure the imports are correct? `AllPatientsPage,
    MedHist` ?

Comment: Yeah I don't see anywhere the `AllPatientsPage` import, you should check that

Comment: @SurajRao I was deleting some of the imports for simplified code, and accidentally deleted it.  It's in the actual code

Comment: can you add the actual code with imports to the question? BTW you have imported `AuthService` and not set as provider